# Someone is trying to access my private server

Tags: spring, maven, web, tomcat, server

I created a private server a few weeks ago. I had it running a simple Spring Boot web application while I tried to learn how to use Spring-Boot-Starter-Security, and create a more complex app. I expected that as soon as I port-forwarded the server open to the Internet, it would get a lot of requests from people trying to find vulnerable websites who are looking to steal information from them. And it did. So for the time being, I had the web application run a simple hello-world program, and did not configure any data transfer from any end.

However, there is this one web request that I do keep getting often, and I'm not sure what it is doing. So I tried to log as much info as I could about the web request, but it is still confusing. I've added the logs below.

Anyone knows or has an idea of what they're trying to do?

```
`2023-02-26T15:27:59.225-05:00  INFO 14000 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.myserver.Controllers.MainController  : New request was received. Request: '/'
2023-02-26T15:27:59.226-05:00  INFO 14000 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.myserver.Controllers.MainController  : The following is the captured IP address: 170.238.39.233
2023-02-26T17:14:10.945-05:00  INFO 14000 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x03m0xa40xa9g0x8d0x850xb30xfb0xcb0x10x0xcb0x87{0xfc0xdfCB0xf10xdf0x910xde\0xe60x950x860xe8?0xad0x17lH ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]`
```

I tried to log as much information as possible of any web requests that comes to my website. However, I still don't know what they're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe try this question at https://security.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: A bot is trying to send a malicious payload intended to exploit a buffer overrun bug in another Webserver than what you are using .  Part of the payload will replace machine code in your server and then do what the new code instructs it to. This is bad, but does not apply to your server.